# How get the context in Robolectric 3

Tags: java, robolectric

I was able to access to the application context in Robolectric 2.x in this way but don't know how to do it in Robolectric 3.

```
return new ClassThatNeedsAContext(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[edited]
Robolectric 2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide

---

[old response]
Looking the Robolectric's sample code maybe I found the solution.
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/f4935bff58ae6a16b1230c3a415973e97713c0fb/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ViewInnerTextTest.java#L22

```
return new ClassThatNeedsAContext(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
```

But I have other problems with some libraries so I was't unable to test it yet.

Comment: Seems a strange work-around, especially given the name they gave it.  I wonder why they removed shadow application.  But this does give the context. +1

Comment: More info here https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide-(Draft)

Comment: @AntonioJose I don't think that link works anymore try this: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: This only gives **context.mLoadedApk.mPackageName="org.robolectric.default"**